# Stop animation and reset position of an element in Raphaël.js

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have this simple animation that moves from side to side, Im trying to create a reset button so that the animation stops and gets back to default, but I cant seem to get i right.

The library I am using is Raphael, but I'm almost sure that with a simple javascript I can reset the values inside the function.

Body onload init function

```
function init() {
  paper = Raphael("loadSVG");

  var bg = paper.rect( 0, 0, "240px", "90px", 0 );
  bg.attr( {fill: "#f3f3ff"} );
  rect1 = paper.rect(150, 20, 50, 50);
  rect1.attr( {fill: "#ffaaaa", "stroke-width": 3} );
}
```

The animation function

```
function moveRect1() {      
  if( xEnd == 150 )
    xEnd = 50;
  else
    xEnd = 150;

  rect1.animate( {x: xEnd}, 1000, "Sine", function (){ 
    moveRect1(); 
  }); 
}
```

and the stop button that don't work :)

```
function stopsvgRect1() {
  rect1.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the stop button to the function you've created.

For example like this:

```
document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
    stopsvgRect1();
};
```

Open **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SF8Z3/)** to see it in action.

---

**edit**:

As the position should also be resetted, you can choose [`Raphael.transform()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) for this action.

Open my [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SF8Z3/1/) to see how it works.

Comment: Works like a charm, but its only "pause" the animation my question was more, how to reset the values of the animation so its gets back to default.

Comment: I've updated my answer, I hope it gets clear by the fiddle itself :)

Comment: AAA GREAT! Thank you very much.
I going to try do ad this so when I press play twice it restart the animation..

If i cant make it Ill send you and email ;)